# react bootstrap form.switch not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, react-bootstrap

I have used react-bootstrap Form. I need to use switch button. If that is true then have to show input box else input box will not show.

```
  const initialState = {
    billingType: "",
    basicFees: false,
    basicFeesCharges: 0
  }
 const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState);
 const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('toggle effect',toggle);
    console.log('use effect form',form);
  }, [toggle,form]);

  const setField = (field, value) => {
    console.log("field", field);
    console.log("value", value);
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [field]: value,
    });
    console.log("set field ", form);
    // Check and see if errors exist, and remove them from the error object:
    if (!!errors[field]) {
      setErrors({
        ...errors,
        [field]: null,
      });
    }
  };
```

**JSX**

```
 <Form.Group>
                          <Form.Check
                            type="switch"
                            name="basicFees"
                            id="custom-switch"
                            label="Basic Fees"
                            checked={toggle}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                              setToggle(!toggle);
                              setField("basicFees",toggle);
                            }}
                          />
                          Here fees {form && form.basicFees ? "on" : "off"}
                          {form && form.basicFees ? (
                            <>
                              <Form.Label>Basic Fees Charges</Form.Label>
                              <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                name="basicFeesCharges"
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  setField("basicFeesCharges", e.target.value)
                                }
                                isInvalid={!!errors.basicFeesCharges}
                              />
                              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                {errors.basicFeesCharges}
                              </Form.Control.Feedback>
                            </>
                          ) : (
                            ""
                          )}
                        </Form.Group>
```

**Problem:** with above code, I am not getting proper result. By default, switch is off. When I first click then ideally it should show input box of `basicFeesCharges` but it does not shows and switch is 'On' at that time. On second click it shows input box of `basicFeesCharges` and switch button is 'Off' that time.
Means state or form does not updating properly onChange even if used `useEffect`. So giving opposite result for switch button.

As a beginner, I am not able to find bug or correct solution even after trying different syntax or code. Please help and guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of your onChange function

```
onChange={(e) => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
    setField("basicFees",toggle);
}}
```

setToggle is asynchronous, so the toggle in setField is still false at 1st time. So try this

```
onChange={(e) => {
    const newToggle = !toggle;
    setToggle(newToggle);
    setField("basicFees", newToggle);
}}
```

Comment: could you please explain more about it? why it worked by taking new const and was not working with `useEffect`? Any reference or guidance so I can learn more about it.

Comment: @ganesh you can check in [reactjs official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. appreciated! it will be useful.

Comment: Hey, I have one more query. If you could please guide on that then will be helpful. Right now, I am using `toggle` as value (checked) of Switch button. How can I use `form.basicFees` as value/checked for Switch button by handling asynchronous issue? or `toggle` is only option ?